# Leading zeros from PDF field to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, pdf

Hopefully this is the correct place to ask this question. I'm pretty much brand new to javascript, but seeing it's similarities to the other languages I write in, it's been pretty easy so far- until now.

I'm writing a script for a button that is clicked when a user is done filling out a grid. The script goes through the fields in the grid, grabs the information, and generates an email. It then sends out a mailto: command with the information that was generated, much easier than the user having to type the email themselves. The problem I'm having is that one of the criteria for a field is a Tax ID, which can sometimes start with a zero, and when I go to assign that field value to a variable, it drops the leading zero. How do I get javascript to keep this leading zero? I've tried declaring a variable with a " " at the beginning to try to force it to recognize the variable as a string, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
if(this.getField("ProviderOne").value != "")
{
    // This is the form return email. Its hardcoded
    // so that the form is always returned to the same address
    var cToAddr = "blank@blank.org";

    // First, get the client CC email address
    var cCCAddr = "blank@blank.com";



    var pOneTaxID = new String(this.getField("ProviderOneTaxID").value); //tring to force string value

    // Set the subject and body text for the email message
    var ProviderOne = this.getField("ProviderOne").value + " NPI:" + this.getField("ProviderOneNPI").value + " Tax ID:" + pOneTaxID;

    var ProviderTwo = this.getField("ProviderTwo").value + " NPI:" + this.getField("ProviderTwoNPI").value + " Tax ID:" + this.getField("ProviderTwoTaxID").value;

    var ProviderThree = this.getField("ProviderThree").value + " NPI:" + this.getField("ProviderThreeNPI").value + " Tax ID:" + this.getField("ProviderThreeTaxID").value;

    var ProviderFour = this.getField("ProviderFour").value + " NPI:" + this.getField("ProviderFourNPI").value + " Tax ID:" + this.getField("ProviderFourTaxID").value;

    var ProviderFive = this.getField("ProviderFive").value + " NPI:" + this.getField("ProviderFiveNPI").value + " Tax ID:" + this.getField("ProviderFiveTaxID").value;

    var cSubLine = this.getField("ProviderOne").value + " ERA setup for [BLANK]";

    var cBody = "To [BLANK], \n \nPlease enroll the following providers to receive [BLANK] through [BLANK] under [BLANK]: \n \n";

    if(this.getField("ProviderOne").value != "")
    cBody += "1. " + ProviderOne + "\n";

    if(this.getField("ProviderTwo").value != "")
    cBody += "2. " + ProviderTwo + "\n";

    if(this.getField("ProviderThree").value != "")
    cBody += "3. " + ProviderThree + "\n";

    if(this.getField("ProviderFour").value != "")
    cBody += "4. " + ProviderFour + "\n";

    if(this.getField("ProviderFive").value != "")
    cBody += "4. " + ProviderFive + "\n";

    cBody += "\n Thank you,\n" + this.getField("ProviderOne").value;

    app.mailMsg({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cCc: cCCAddr, cBCc: "", cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody});
}
else
{
    app.alert("Please enter at least one payer into the grid above.", 1, 0, "Unfilled Form");
    this.getField("ProviderOne").setFocus();
}
```

Thanks a ton for taking the time to read through this, and even more thanks to you if you can help me find a solution.

-Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Instead of grabbing the value using getField("FieldName").value, I grabbed it using .valueAsString. Hopefully this is useful if someone finds it down the road.

Comment: This is the standard way to get leading zeroes from a field. You may, however, be prepared that JavaScript may still be able to turn it into a number. In order to prevent that, you would add ' event.value = " " + event.value ; ' to the Validate event of the concerned field.